# How does google know about my youtube preferences when I use private Firefox window?

Tags: youtube, privacy

I launched Firefox in private mode and opened youtube. The first thing I see is recommended videos based on my prevoius watches. But I am not logged in, I am in private mode, why does youtube suggests this to me? I think it's privacy violation. Am I right?

Comment: Off-Topic: All trackers are "privacy violations" in my opinion. But Google can store info about you in cookies -- which can be read in private mode, afaik -- and still use that to generate specific ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internet in general is a privacy violation, whether you are in private mode are not. As mrunion said in the comments, Google can store information about you in cookies (or even in your cache) which "Private" mode can still access.

Try clearing your cache and deleting cookies. If you want your browsing to be more "Private" I would suggest that you disable cookies altogether, although this can negatively affect how many web sites perform as they may depend on those cookies.